# How to loop over an array of arrays using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array of arrays. I want to be able to loop over each array and for every array I want to add new keys or update existing values.

Here is what I have

```
    var values = [];

    values['123'] = [];
    values['456'] = [];
    values['123']['x1'] = 'value 1';
    values['123']['x2'] = 'value 2';
```

I want to loop over the values array, and add new keys to the array for each array. (I.e `values['123']` and `values['456']`)

Here is what I tried

```
$.each(values, function(index, value){

  value['x1'] = 'new value 1';
  value['x10'] = 'new value 10';
  value['x20'] = 'new value 20';
  console.log(value);

});
```

The console shows this error

```
TypeError: value is undefined
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9exfbd5n/1/)

How can I correcly loop over each array item and update the original array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually for your case you need to use `Object`, not `Array`

For constructing **non-numeric** indexes you should use `{}`

`{}` - for constructing [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object),
`[]` - for constructing [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

[jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) can be used to iterate over both **objects** and **arrays**.

Try this code

```
$(function() {
    $('#x').click(function(e) {
        var values = {}; // here

        values['123'] = {}; // here
        values['456'] = {}; // here
        values['123']['x1'] = 'value1';
        values['123']['x2'] = 'value2';


        $.each(values, function(index, value) {

            value['x1'] = 'new value 1';
            value['x10'] = 'new value 10';
            value['x20'] = 'new value 20';
            console.log(value);

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: That worked! Can you please tell me what is the difference between {} and [] ?

Comment: @MikeA Here, **values** is being initialised as an object (see the **{}**) rather than an array. **$.each()** function treats **123** & **456** as keys in case of object, however, in case of array it treats them as indexes. Thats why I added the **values[index]!== undefined** condition in my code below.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help

Comment: @MikeA I've added some links and info

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your `values` array is getting initialized with indexes `123` and `456`. So, the `$.each()` function assumes the array length to be `457` and thus starts from element index `0`, though there is no value at that index.

In order to overcome this, you can simply make the following change and it will work-

```
$.each(values, function(index, value){
    if(values[index] !== undefined) { 
        value['x1'] = 'new value 1';
        value['x10'] = 'new value 10';
        value['x20'] = 'new value 20';

        //Update the new values in the values object.
        values[index] = value;
        console.log(value);
    }
});
```

Comment: That removed the error but values is now empty and it should not.

Comment: Check my updated answer. The **values** object was not getting updated with the latest values earlier. It should work as required now.

Comment: As per your question, since you asked how to loop an array of arrays, this should be the answer. Since here, I didn't make any changes in your array structure. The current accepted answer makes a change in the underlying structure by simply changing the main array into object.